# What is the relationship between target-densitydpi and window.innerWidth with Android H5

Tags: android, html, android-webview, viewport

My genymotion emulator is Google Nexus7 -4.1.1 API16- 800*1280 .
When I use webview to load HTML5 on Android, I was confused with the relationship between target-densitydpi and window.innerWidth.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,**target-densitydpi=device-dpi**,initial-scale=1.0,minimum=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">

$(function(){alert(window.innerWidth);   //get the viewport width
          alert(window.devicePixelRatio);})  //  always is 1.3312499523162842  no matter what target-densitydpi is
```

I do some tests:

```
                                   window.innerWidth
```

`**target-densitydpi=device-dpi:**         800`

`**target-densitydpi=low-dpi:**            452`

`**target-densitydpi=middle-dpi:**         602`

`**target-densitydpi=high-dpi:**           909`

`**ignore   target-densitydpi:**           602`

How to calculate the window.inerWidth? Has something to do with window.devicePixelRatio?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid using `target-densitydpi` if possible. This attribute is non-standard, and is actually deprecated in modern versions of Android WebView.

Roughly, `target-densitydpi` defines a scaling coefficient for CSS pixels to screen pixels ratio. It is calculated in the following way:

- for `device-dpi`, as 1 / device-scale-factor; in your case: `1 / (4/3) = 0.75`;
- for `low-dpi`, `middle-dpi` and `high-dpi` it does not depend on the device characteristics, and is calculated as 160 divided by 120, 160 and 240, respectively, yielding `4 / 3`, `1` and `2 / 3`;

Then the CSS width is scaled by dividing on the calculated value. In your case, the unscaled CSS width is 602 `(800 / 1.33124...)`. There also funny rounding adjustments involved, that's why the results can be off by some units.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have some questions following:                                       as you said,                                                                                             452 =(800 /(4/3)) ?  not right !    and how 909 is calculated?  It has something wrong with the scaling coefficient?

Comment: I didn't say 452 =(800 /(4/3)), I said, 452 ~ (602 / (4 / 3)). 909 ~ (602 / (2 / 3)). 602 is the unscaled CSS width.

Comment: You said: for device-dpi, as 1 / device-scale-factor; in your case: 1 / (4/3) = 0.75, but  why device-scale-factor is 4/3??And                                                                           why 602 (800 / 1.33124...) is the unscaled CSS width ? why 800 is not the unscaled css width? Thank you!

Comment: device-scale-factor is 4/3 -- this is roughly the same as `window.devicePixelRatio` that you reported to be 1.33..... My good advice to you is to read this classical piece http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html about the relationship between CSS and physical screen pixels, that should explain why CSS width is 600px in your case.

Comment: Thank for your answer. We all know  window.devicePixelRatio =pixel/dip , dip means device-independent pixel,   It seems that  window.devicePixelRatio  can't be controlled. **and some devices show that window.devicePixelRatio =2 **  , why?Is window.devicePixelRatio fixed by producer?

Comment: Yes, devicePixelRatio depends on the device screen density and can't be changed.